# Numpad keycodes for "+" when numlock is on

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to get the keycodes from "+" on numlock while numlock is one, the thing is I need to have it one because of mouse keys, long story short I need + on numpad as a mouse key while I need to detect the input.

What I've tried so far:

```
KeyPressed = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Add)
```

I've looked through all the enums for numpad.

I've looked on the internet.

If you need more context let me know.

By the way, I'm tagging C# because I'm thinking it might be the same keycodes.

Comment: `By the way, I'm tagging C# because I'm thinking it might be the same keycodes.` - **Yes, it is!** It is the same for every .NET Framework-based language, or for _every_ programming language for that matter. The language doesn't determine the set of key codes.

Comment: Have you look at [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)? if i understand correctly you need the key codes.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε : All virtual-key codes are mapped to the [**`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), which he's already utilizing.

Comment: It works just fine when i disable numpad but i most have it enabled to use mouse keys `KeyPressed = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Add) ` .

Answer (score 1):

In C#, Keys.Add is correct for both states of the NumLock key.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        short? previousState = null;
        while (true)
        {
            var state = GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Add);
            if (state != previousState)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(state);
                previousState = state;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SteffenCH : Please explain what these "mouse keys" are.

Comment: Its a part of windows, you can enable them and navigate the mouse through numpad they can be activated through " ease of access "

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer Its the same for windows 10.